# torch.utils.data.dataloader outputs TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

So im trying to learn pytorch and i got this code from a tutorial and its just there to import a mnist dataset but it outputs "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"
In the tutorial     "dataloader" was written as     "Dataloader" but when i run it like that it outputs "AttributeError: module 'torch.utils.data' has no attribute 'Dataloader'"

The data downloaded inside a file mnist but i dont know if it is complete

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optom
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
kwargs={}
train=torch.utils.data.dataloader(datasets.MNIST("mnist",train=True,download=True,transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize((0.1307),(0.3081,) )] ) ),batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's neither `dataloader` nor `Dataloader` but `DataLoader` :)

Side-note: if you're new to PyTorch, consider using the newest version 1.0. `torch.autograd.Variable` is deprecated as of PyTorch 0.4.1 (I believe) so you're either using an older version of PyTorch or an outdated tutorial.

Comment: also thank you for bringing the tensorflowversion to my attention i now upgraded

Comment: although i compiled code that uses torch.autograd.Variable in version 1 and it still worked