# how do i deal with torchvision datasets

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, torchvision

I am using a torchvision dataset called MNIST. I run the code in my python project to download it. Do I need to delete the code I wrote, or could I just continue writing my ai? Would the download code disturb it or redownload the whole dataset?

The code I use to download it:

```
train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))
```

The guy from the tutorial is using jupyter notebook, but I am using PyCharm.
What do i need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave that in there, you need that to define your datasets: The `download=True` flag means that the dataset is only downloaded as long as it doesn't already exist in the specified folder: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#mnist

Comment: thank you so much for the info, anyway the tutorial i use is https://youtu.be/i2yPxY2rOzs?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdeMyHEYc0gxFpYwHY2Qfdh.

Comment: Hey, i found a nother eror, in the video, the next two lines, after the code i type above, it says that utils is not found?

Comment: That seems like it belongs to anothe rpart of the code. Maybe you forgot to import or install something?

Comment: i import everything the video recomends, i am still confused, i am using pytorch 1.4.0 does the video use a difrent version of pytorch, what do i need to do ?

Comment: i also use a difrent part of someones code, link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693999/torch-utils-data-dataloader-outputs-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable

Comment: i just tried it out but it stils couse an eror, i also tried importing every import statement used, but it still couse an eror

Comment: as this is a problem that is completely outside of the scope of the original question you posted, please consider asking a new one and add ad much information as possible about your problem.

Comment: i made a new question basen on the problem, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181608/pytorch-cant-shuffle-the-dataset