# pytorch can't shuffle the dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

i am trying to make an ai with the mnist dataset from torchvision and makeing it with pytorch, but when i type some of the code that shuffle the data, and run it, it say:

```
    trainset = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
AttributeError: module 'torch.utils.data' has no attribute 'Dataloader'
```

i tried a difrent method but it still do not work, and it says:

```
    trainset = torch.autograd.Variable.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True) 
AttributeError: type object 'Variable' has no attribute 'DataLoader'
```

the code i use is:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datasets


train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

trainset = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
testset = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(test, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

for data in trainset:
    print(data)
    break
```

the eror from this code:

```
    trainset = torch.utils.data.Dataloader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
AttributeError: module 'torch.utils.data' has no attribute 'Dataloader'
```

i tried a new version but it still not working:

```
import torch
import numpy as np 
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms, datasets


train = datasets.MNIST("", train=True, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()]))

test = datasets.MNIST("", train=False, download=True,
                       transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

trainset = torch.autograd.Variable.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
testset = torch.autograd.Variable.DataLoader(test, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

for data in trainset:
    print(data)
    break
```

the eror from this code:

```
    trainset = torch.autograd.Variable.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True) 
AttributeError: type object 'Variable' has no attribute 'DataLoader'
```

i am stil confused why it is not working,i was folowing a tutorial but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple typo: `Dataloader` -> [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) (capital `L`).

Try:

```py
 trainset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```